# Rails Paperclip not showing uploaded images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've just started using paperclip gem and I'm having some problems with it. I set up the path and url in my model file such as:

```
 has_attached_file :picture,
   :styles => { :medium => "500x500>", :thumb => "120x90#" },
   :url => '/public/images/guests/:style/:id.:extension',
   :path => ":rails_root/public/images/guests/:style/:id.:extension"
```

when I send it from my form, the server saves the file exactly where it was supposed to do, but when I check the following url:
mysite.com/public/images/guests/medium/1.jpg there's routing error.
I don't know what to do, can you please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you hosting the app?

Answer (score 0):

Url should be

```
:url => "/assets/images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

while path should be

```
:path => ":rails_root/public/assets/images/guests/:style/:id/:basename.:extension"
```

Comment: Still not working @Athar. When I remove the path parameter, the url works fine, but when I try to set it, it doesn't work at all!

Comment: can you share what do you get when you run this. 
     picture.url(:medium)

Comment: okay try this please. this should work.
:path          => ":rails_root/public/assets/images/guests/:style/:id/:basename.:extension",
:url           => "/assets/images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

Comment: i have also updated my answer according to requirements

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
has_attached_file : picture, 
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
:url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", 
:styles => { :medium => "500x500>", :thumb => "120x90#" },
:default_url => "path to default image"
```